# Steps to partially differentiate the following reduced function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the partial derivative of Q with respect to b and d.

The book I'm using shows me the answer, but not the steps. The function is:

Q = (d - b) / (a + c)

here is how I think it would be done:

The partial derivative of Q with respect to b is:
(d - b) / (a + c) = (d - b)(a + c)^-1
then drop d as it is a constant and put -b to -1 as it is the variable.
-b/(a + c)
but the book shows that it should be 1/(a+b)

For the partial differential of Q with respect to d I do get the right answer
(d - b) / (a + c) = 1/(a + c) though, but I'm not sue if that is just luck, rather than using the right method.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the function $$Q=\frac{d-b}{a+c}$$ As long as you do not need the derivative of $Q$ with respect to $a$ or $c$, the denominator is a constant. So, $$Q'_b=\frac{1}{a+c} (d-b)'_b=\frac{-1}{a+c}$$ Similarly, $$Q'_d=\frac{1}{a+c} (d-b)'_d=\frac{1}{a+c}$$ So, there must be a typo in your book and **you are right** !

If you need to consider the other derivatives which involve a quotient, jus post and I shall continue.

Comment: Ah man! I spent hours trying this, and I was right, lol!

Big thanks though, this was really helpful. I like the way you take out the 1/a+c. That makes it clearer how to differentiate.

Could you do the numerator too, I'd like to check if I'm doing it right, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the derivatives with respect to $a$ and $c$ ?

Comment: ops! Yeah, denominator I meant  ;)

I think I should be using the chain rule with (a + c) right?